# How to execute a SQL Server stored procedure after a data flow task in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am new to SSIS. I am trying to create an ETL pipeline to automate the updating and deleting process for a database.

I have created a data flow task which reads the Excel file and sends the data to respective staging tables in SQL Server.

[image: Data Flow]

For the data to be updated in the main database, it has to go through some transformation in the staging tables. I have created a stored procedure that will enforce these changes.

I want the stored procedure to get called right after data is loaded through the data flow task to the staging tables rather than me going to SSMS to manually execute the stored procedure.

[image: Stored procedure]

I have tried adding the "Execute SQL Task" on the control flow tab but not getting any results.

I would like to further add many more transformations in this whole process in future steps. Any ideas on how to make this whole process more convenient would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Data Flow Task] -> [Execute SQL Task]

Configure the `Execute SQL Task` with a Direct Input value of

```
EXECUTE dbo.MasterQuery;
```

Based on the image of your stored procedure, it would appear you have a logic error in there.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.OutlookDataStg WHERE [Flag] = 'Outlook')
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.OutlookDataStg
    SET [Data Type] = 'Outlook'
    WHERE [Flag] = 'Actual'

-- Cut off at this point
END
```

The logic provided is

> If there is at least one row in the table dbo.OutlookDataStg where the value flag is Outlook, then update the same table but set the Data type to Outlook for any rows with a flag of Actual.

Unless you have some unusual condition, it would see you've mixed your Flag and Data Type values